# NHibernate JOIN mapping fails when the mapped field is moved to a base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-inheritance

Having two model classes with many common fields, I decided to create a base class  and both of them to inherit from it.

The existent model classes already came with map classes.

All the common fields which are now inherited in the child classes are virtual to keep NHibernate happy and they are all mapping alright, except for one...

This my case:

```
public class BaseClass : EntityBase<Guid>
{
   //This is not complaining 
   public virtual string Text { get; set; }

   //This is complaining
   public virtual Guid TouchGuid { get; set; }
}

public class A : BaseClass
{
    //inherited + specific stuff
}

public class B : BaseClass
{
    //inherited + specific stuff
}
```

Now these are the mapping classes:

```
public class AMap : ClassMapping<A>
{
    //Mapping the ID inherited from EntityBase class
    Id(x => x.Id, mapper =>
    {
        mapper.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
        mapper.Column("Pk_MenuItemId");
    });

    //Mapping the common field inherited, doesn't complain !
    Property(x => x.Mnemonic);

    //This is the one which is complaining, keep in mind it was working
    //before creating the base class and move the TouchGuid property in it.
    Join("Touch", x =>
    {
        x.Key(k =>
        {
            k.Column("EntityId");
            k.ForeignKey("PK_AClassId");
            k.OnDelete(OnDeleteAction.Cascade);
            k.Unique(true);
        });
        x.Property(p => p.TouchGuid);
    });
}

public class BMap : ClassMapping<B>
{
    //Same map as for class A
}
```

Whenever I run the program, loading the data from those classes (tables), will fail saying it couldn't find the TouchGuid column on the A table respectively B table, here is the error:

[image]

Yes, there is common data between A and B tables but I can't change the db scheme, it would add too much complexity now.

Do I need to create a table for the base class too ? I would like to avoid created a new table if possible.

Any hints of what could be wrong ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe NHibernate assumes a DB schema with multiple tables because it defaults to implicit polymorphism mode. Try setting polymorphism=explicit in the mappings.

Comment: OK, I got the idea ! If I only have one child, for example just the A class, it will perfectly work but whenever I create the second child it is failing. This make sense for the polymorphic thing but I didn't found a way to set it to explicit in fluent nhibernate, I've tried Polymorphism.Explicit(); but the word Polymorphism doesn't exist in the current context unfortunately.

Can you please add some code to how to set the polymorphism to explicit in fluent nhibernate ? Thank you Jonas !

Comment: I've been reading about this and seems that polymorphic can be set to explicit only with XML mappings, is this so ?

Comment: I think you're using the built in mapping-by-code, not Fluent NHibernate?

Comment: On second thoughts, have you tried making the base class abstract?

Comment: Yes, I am using mapping-by-code, creating a class map which inherits from ClassMapping<A> and in its constructor I have all the mappings Jonas

Comment: Yes, the base class is abstract, but not helping though :(

Comment: Ok. I can't find the explicit syntax for mapping by code right now, unfortunately

Comment: OK, no porbs, I will try to sort it out and if this will solve the issue, I will accept this answer as the fix to my problem, thank you.

Comment: This answer is the fix to the described problem, I managed to fix it in some other way. It would be perfect if map-by-code would allow to set the polymorphic to explicit but unfortunately, it doesn't.